# Windows script batch to copy files from different folders to other folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The easiest way to explain the problem is by an example.

I want to do something like this:

```
file x in /path_1/A/x copy in /path_2/A/
file x in /path_1/B/x copy in /path_2/B/
...
...
file x in /path_1/Z/x copy in /path_2/Z/
```

From command line with a script in Windows.

Comment: `xcopy /S /I /path_1 /path_2`

Comment: No, beacuse with this command I copy all the files in the subdirectories, but I want to copy only x.

Comment: This proves that "The easiest way to explain the problem is NOT by an example", but an explanation is always required! See my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

cd /path_1
for /D %%d in (*) do (
   if exist "%%d/x" (
      if not exist "/path_2/%%d" md "/path_2/%%d"
      copy "%%d/x" "/path_2/%%d"
   )
)
```